# React useState variable changes are not reflected

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with some checkboxes on it, in the event that the checkboxes are not checked when the form is submitted, I display a modal asking the user to check them.  Whether that modal is displayed is based on whether a state variable called "boxesChecked" is set to true or false.  The catch is that once the user has acknowledged that the boxes are not checked this variable is set to true and the modal won't be displayed again if the user proceeds to submit again without the checkboxes checked.  There is an onClose method for the modal that sets the value of boxesChecked to true.

The boxesChecked variable is initialized like this:

```
const [boxesChecked, setBoxesChecked] = React.useState(false)
```

And this is the onClose function:

```
const onContactModalClose = () => {
  setBoxesChecked(true)
}
```

In running this numerous times, for some reason the value is never set to true and the modal is always displayed.  I added a useEffect to monitor the value of boxes checked like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Here boxesChecked seems to always be true
  console.log('Boxes checked in useEffect: ', boxesChecked)
}, [boxesChecked])
```

I am also logging the value just prior to an if statement in my code that would determine whether to show the modal.

```
// Here though, boxesChecked is always set to false
console.log('Should I display the modal? boxesChecked is : ', boxesChecked)
if (boxesChecked || (emailChecked && textChecked)) {
```

The logs show this on the first time that submit is clicked with the boxes unchecked:

[image]

Clicking the second time with no checkboxes checked yields this in the console:

[image]

For some reason boxesChecked is false again, despite useEffect indicating that it changed to true, also the useEffect callback isn't called a second time indicating that as far as that is concerned, the value never changed from true.

I have seen a number of questions on here suggesting that this is because the state updater function is asynchronous, but that doesn't entirely make sense to me, for one I'm not trying to use the value immediately after setting it using the updater function, and additionally, the value appears to have been changed, but isn't reflected outside of the useEffect callback.  Can anybody provide some help on this?

Comment: You should show a **producible example**. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use a simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq) for it.

Comment: Without seeing the code I guess its because of closures.